# Proper way to get possibly through Cocoa Bindings the last element of a relationship in Core Data

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsset

I have a managed-object X with a relationship to a list of [1:N) Y objects. (X and Y objects are stored using Core Data)

I would like to find the proper (and more convenient) way to obtain the latest inserted Y object. The "name" attribute of this Y object should be shown in the graphic possibly through Cocoa Bindings.

I know that all Ys are inserted into a NSSet, so there is no defined order. However, each Y has a "timestamp" attribute, so when I say "the latest inserted Y object" I actually mean "the Y with the latest timestamp".

Any help will be appreciated: I searched all the documentation but have not found anything that could help me.

Answer (score 2):

In The KVC Programming Guide's [Collection Operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) section, the description for @max says

> The @max operator compares the values of the property specified by the key path to the right of the operator and returns the maximum value found. The maximum value is determined using the compare: method of the objects at the specified key path. The compared property objects must support comparison with each other. If the value of the right side of the key path is nil, it is ignored.
>
> The following example returns the maximum value of the date values (date of the latest transaction) for the Transaction objects in transactions:

```
NSDate *latestDate = [transactions valueForKeyPath: "@max.date"];
```

> The latestDate value (formatted) is Jul 15, 2010.

Comment: Cool. But how can I bound the NSView in which I want to show the title of the y with the latest timestamp? Unfortunately, the key paths selection.ys.@max.timestamp.title ot selection.ys.timestamp@max.title do not work...

Comment: Do timestamps in your app have titles? Why would you put one there? (The other clue being, "Why are you attempting to reference a title via the timestamp keypath?")

Comment: My question is that I would like to find the latest inserted Y object because its "name" (not "title", sorry) attribute should be shown in the UI possibly through Cocoa Bindings.

With the key-path you suggested, "selection.ys.@max.timestamp", I can obtain the *timestamp* of the latest inserted Y object. A big step forward and very cool. But how can I obtain the *title* of this object? Thanks for your time!